# Yes/No . Is $f$ bounded in a neighbourhood of $(0,0) ?$

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} \frac {x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} & \text{for }  (x ,y)
\neq (0,0)\\ 0 \  & \text {for }    (x,y) =(0,0)  \end{cases}$

Is  $f$   bounded  in a neighbourhood  of $(0,0) ?$

My attempt : I think $f$ is   bounded  in a neighbourhood  of $(0,0) $

take $x= r \cos \theta$  and $y= r\sin \theta$

$$\Big|\frac {x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\Big|=\Big|\frac {r^2 \sin^2 \theta -r^2 \cos^2 \theta }{r^2 \sin^2 \theta +r^2 \cos^2 \theta}\Big|\le \Big|\frac {r^2 (\sin^2 \theta - \cos^2 \theta) }{r^2( \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta)}\Big|\le |\sin^2 \theta - \cos^2 \theta |\le |1+1|\le 2$$

Also, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac {x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{0-0}{0+0}=0$

Comment: $0/0$ is NOT $0$. This is an indeterminant form, one that cannot be evaluated because one cannot divide by zero. So the last limit calculation is incorrect.

Comment: okay @ndhanson3

Comment: Also, the inequality $|\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta| \leq |1+1|$ is only true luckily. You need to use the triangle inequality: $|\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta|\leq |\sin^2\theta| + |\cos^2\theta|\leq 1+1$.

Comment: @ndhanson3 on this [link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/what-is-0-0/)  it is given that $0/0 =1$

Comment: In that link, the question says "I will attempt to prove $0/0=1$", and you are tasked with finding the flawed logic...

Comment: @ndhanson3 .  If you tell 10 people that 0/0  is an indeterminate form and then ask them to explain what that means, at least 5 of them  can't...... I prefer to be more blunt and say 0/0 doesn't exist.

Comment: Your link does NOT say 0/0=1. Click on the box "Reveal the correct answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $f(x)$ is actually bounded everywhere, not just in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Every point that is not $(0,0)$ can take advantage of the argument using $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, which you have almost correct. Some of the **inequalities** are in fact **equalities**, and as I mentioned in the comments, one of your inequalities is only luckily correct:

$$\left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|
=\left|\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2\sin^2\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta}\right|
=\left|\frac{r^2(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}{r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)}\right|
=|\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta|\\\leq|\cos^2\theta|+|\sin^2\theta|\leq1+1=2
$$

Comment: In fact, $\cos^2-\sin^2\theta=\cos2\theta$, so $|\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta|=|\cos2\theta|\leq 1$, so the whole function is bounded by $-1$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(0,0)\ne(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ then $$|f(x,y)|=\frac {|x^2+(-y^2)|}{x^2+y^2}\le \frac {|x^2|+|(-y^2)|}{x^2+y^2}=\frac {x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}=1.$$